# Getting a Cognito unique identifier for user related data in an internal database

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito

This seems like an obvious use case but I can't seem to find any explanation describing the best way to save Cognito user related data internally in a database. So for example, I can create a client side application (I'm using React and Amplify) to login using Cognito and then pass the Idtoken as a bearer token to the Web API. I can even call cognito to authorize access to controller methods on my backend web api (.net core). What I can't seem to figure out to get a unique identifier for the user so I can relate information using the User ID as a foreign key in my backend database.

For example, I have a User that can create Comments. In my database, comment has a userID column. How can I get the userID from cognito to save the comment? So if I have a method GetAllCommentsForUser, I can pass the bearer token, retrieve the unique user ID and then query the db? Am I missing something because again it seems like a pretty common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) API call to retrieve the unique sub id of the user related to the identity pool. You can write your IAM policies dynamically to include the sub variable which is linked to this id. So, for example, you can create a "folder" in s3 with name as the sub id of user. Your dynamically written policy will then restrict the user so that he can only access files inside the folder. 
In your use case you can put the sub as userId in your table.